# Please help me get this return the values

Tags: java, html, regex

I know using regex is not the best way to search for HTML tags in Java. But this is the first step of the project that I am working on and I am going to have to search for non HTML stuff as well. So why isn't the following code working?

```
public static String tagValue(String inHTML, String tag) throws DataNotFoundException
{
    String value = null;

    String searchFor = "/<" + tag + ">(.*?)<\\/" + tag + "\\>/";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(searchFor);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inHTML);

    return matcher.toString();

}
```

Comment: Would you add some details about "how" it is not working? Any stack trace, or just no result, or anything else?

Comment: You can match text nodes (which is, I assume, what you mean by "non HTML stuff") against a pattern using either XQuery or XPath. XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0 both support regular expressions for this purpose. No need to match the HTML with a regex as well.

Answer (score 2):

`matcher.toString()` does not do the seaching. Use `matcher.find()` or  `matcher.matches()`

Here is the official example of how to use `Pattern` and `Matcher`.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you first try your regular expression on a fex samples, as an example using [this online tester](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm).

Once you have found a good regexp, you can introduce it in your code.

As an example, the followingregular expression (already tested)

```
Regular Expression
Original Expression <([a-zA-Z]+)([^>]*)>(.*)</\1>
as a Java string    "<([a-zA-Z]+)([^>]*)>(.*)</\\1>"
```

Provides the following test results :

```
Target String           group(0)                    group(1)    group(2)        group(3)
<b>text</b>                 <b>text</b>                 b           text
<a href="pouet">link</a>    <a href="pouet">link</a>    a           href="pouet"    link
<footnote></footnote>       <footnote></footnote>       footnote
```

Which seems rather good, no ?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using a regex that comes from a PHP background - there are delimiters around it (slashes) that you need to remove if you want to regex to work in Java:

```
String searchFor = "<" + tag + ">(.*?)</" + tag + ">";
```

Otherwise your regex will be looking for literal slashes around your tags which presumably aren't there.

Comment: I don’t think their pattern will do what they want it to do on text like `<ul><ul>...</ul></ul>`, since it’s the first `<ul>` followed by the first `</ul>`, not by the corresponding one. You can’t do properly recursive patterns in Java’s simplistic regex language, but you could exclude brackets.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this simple of searching and can't figure out your own REGEX, then you've violated the KISS principle.  Try this instead:

```
public static String tagValue(String inHTML, String tag) throws DataNotFoundException {
    int start = inHTML.first("<"+tag+">");
    if(start < 0) throw DataNotFoundException("Couldn't find beginning "+tag+" tag.");
    int end = inHtml.first("</"+tag+">", start);
    if(end < 0) throw DataNotFoundException("Couldn't find ending "+tag+" tag.");
    return intHTML.substring(start,end);
}
```

Note: I haven't run this, so typo errors may exist.  Feel free to correct them (and delete this note).